# How to handle duplicate records in SQL Server joins?

Tags: sql-server

I have been trying to join three tables together in SQL Server using a concatenated field as my unique identifier but I noticed that it has been returning duplicated records.

- Table A has 25'003 records
- Table B has 29'387 records
- Table C has 22'938 records

The objective is to join B and C to A.

The result has 48'732 records.

Here is a snippet of my query:

```
Select 
    a.xxxx, a.yyyy, b.sdsd, c.dffgg
From 
    [table A] a 
Left Join 
    [table B] b on a.pkey = b.pkey
Left Join 
    [table C] c on a.pkey = c.pkey.
```

Table A:

```
PeriodRef   OfficeCode  OfficeDesc  TaskServLineCode    TaskServLineDesc    ServLineDiv PartnerCode PartnerName ManagerCode ManagerName BillerCode  BillerName  ClientCode  ClientName  BusCatCode  BusCatDesc  GroupCode   GroupDesc   TaskCode    TaskDesc    TaskDateOpen    TaskDateTerminate   InvNumber   InvDate LTDInv  LTDFee  LTDVat  LTDCn   LTDRec  LTDPLFC YTDInv  YTDFee  YTDVat  YTDCn   YTDRec  YTDPLFC PTDInv  PTDFee  PTDVat  PTDCn   PTDRec  PTDPLFC CBal    BalCurr Bal30   Bal60   Bal90   Bal120  Bal150  Bal180  CM Provision    PM Provision    CM Provision movement   Start CY Provision  YTD Provision movement
201710  1   LAGOS   A100    e   a   AAA xcv rg  vgg AOA iyh erd2    tggtt   yue jd  kdk weeer   INV Invoice NULL    NULL    5yj 00:00.0 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
201710  1   LAGOS   A100    e   a   AAA cbvc    rfgt    ghh ZZZZZ   ssf 34ef    etg assw    kjkl    kdk jdkjf   INV Invoice NULL    NULL    6uuj    00:00.0 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
201710  1   LAGOS   A100    e   a   AAA zcvv    ffbb    ddg EOK adf 23df    sss asd ieel    kdk dghjg;js    CT07    sff 00:00.0 00:00.0 56  00:00.0 0   4837500 237500  0   5075000 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Table B and C have the same schema. the only difference between them is the period.

PS: The tables does not have a unique identifier that is why I concatenated some columns to get the identifier. Thanks all.

Comment: pkey is not unique...

Comment: it would help if you included the schema and sample data to test against

Comment: About all we can tell you is that there are obviously multiple rows in tables b and/or c that meet the join criteria.

Comment: Why are you using `LEFT JOIN`? Use `Distinct` to filter out duplicates. What should you be getting for results?

Comment: impossible to help unless you provide us with sample data from all tables and expected result

Comment: i have edited the question to include a sample data from the tables.

Answer (score 0):

That's a bit of a nebulous question, "how do you handle duplicate records in joins?", so here's a very generic answer (that might be what you are looking for, or might get you started):

```
WITH UniqueKeys AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT pkey FROM [table A]
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT pkey FROM [table B]
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT pkey FROM [table C])
SELECT
    u.pkey,
    CASE WHEN a.pkey IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS in_a,
    CASE WHEN b.pkey IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS in_b,
    CASE WHEN c.pkey IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS in_c
FROM
    UniqueKeys u
    LEFT JOIN [table A] a ON a.pkey = u.pkey
    LEFT JOIN [table B] a ON b.pkey = u.pkey
    LEFT JOIN [table C] a ON c.pkey = u.pkey;
```

This is my basic approach when I am dealing with data that might have duplicates or "missing" keys across a number of tables:

- make a master list of the keys that do exist, across all three tables.  The key here is that I am using UNION so any duplicates are removed;
- use this as my anchor point to LEFT JOIN to each of the tables.

This will then give me a list showing whether each key exists in tables a, b or c.

I guess you would want to extend this, e.g. you could add a constraint that keys are only listed if there are duplicates in the source table, etc.?

If indeed there are duplicates, e.g. pkey "XYZ123" exists four times in table A, then you might want to change the base query to GROUP BY u.pkey, and take the MAX() value for the CASE statements?  You could even count the number of instances, by making this a SUM() instead, but then you would need to avoid "multiplying the results up".

So your query would now look something like this:

```
WITH UniqueKeys AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT pkey FROM [table A]
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT pkey FROM [table B]
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT pkey FROM [table C])
SELECT
    u.pkey,
    SUM(CASE WHEN a.pkey IS NOT NULL THEN a.instances ELSE 0 END) AS in_a,
    SUM(CASE WHEN b.pkey IS NOT NULL THEN b.instances ELSE 0 END) AS in_b,
    SUM(CASE WHEN c.pkey IS NOT NULL THEN c.instances ELSE 0 END) AS in_c
FROM
    UniqueKeys u
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS instances FROM [table A] WHERE pkey = u.pkey) a ON a.pkey = u.pkey
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS instances FROM [table B] WHERE pkey = u.pkey) b ON b.pkey = u.pkey
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS instances FROM [table C] WHERE pkey = u.pkey) c ON c.pkey = u.pkey
GROUP BY
    u.pkey;
```

Answer (score 0):

Question not clear. See if this helps you.
Whatever way you generate your Identifier, if it has more than on one corresponding key then it going to return duplicates.

Please check the counts of 3 tables.

```
select count(pkey) from [table A]
select count(distinct pkey) from [table A]
select count(pkey) from [table B]
select count(distinct pkey) from [table B]
select count(pkey) from [table C]
select count(distinct pkey) from [table C]
```

If the count and distinct count from table b and table c values differ, then that mean the key is duplicated in Table B and Table C. So your join always return more than one row when you match with Table A.